# Correlation coefficient using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, correlation

I'm developing a correlation coefficient by hand in Python. I already developed using NumPy arrays but my matrices are big and NumPy is taking a long time.

This is the code I already have:

```
def corrcoef_2(x):
c = np.zeros((x.shape[0],x.shape[0],x.shape[0]))
for k1 in range(0,x.shape[0]):
    for k2 in range(0,x.shape[0]):
       c[k1,k2] = correlation(x[k1,:],x[k2,:])
return c

def correlation(T1, T2):
    numerator = np.mean((T1 - T1.mean()) * (T2 - T2.mean()))
    denominator = T1.std() * T2.std()
    if denominator == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        result = numerator / denominator
        return result
```

I can't use Numpy corrcoef or TensorFlow native method because after I want to generalize my corrcoef function to three dimensions.

Is it possible to do the same I'm doing above but with TensorFlow? How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this relatively straightforward in tensorflow. Most Numpy operations are available in tensorflow and often take the same name and form (tensorflow makes some effort to mimic numpy).

A few things that will help you in doing so:

- Keep in mind that tensorflow is different than numpy in that you need to first define all the math operations (these are symbols), and then ask tensorflow to compute a particular value using `sess.run`. You should write your code such that you have a `build_graph` function where all the tensorflow operations are defined. After you create a session `with tf.Session() as sess:` you should not need to create any tensorflow operatoins after that point (you can do so, but that usually means you're doing something buggy).
- Note that you can perform operations like `+ - * /` just as you do in numpy, tensorflow overrides these operations to replace them with tensorflow constructs like `tf.sum` and `tf.multiply` as appropriate.
- You may *NOT* use any numpy operations in tensorflow. Everything needs to be a tensorflow operation. If you absolutely can't do without some python code you must wrap it explicitly with `tf.py_func`, but if you feel some need to do that post a question on SO validating why it's necessary, it shouldn't be in your case.

Your `build_graph` function should look pretty similar to the code you have presented, just with a lot of `tf.` functions in place of the numpy equivalent.

Once you get this running in tensorflow you will be able to run these operations on the GPU quite trivially as long as you have a CUDA enabled GPU and `tensorflow-gpu` installed, there's nothing special needed to use the GPU, tensorflow will assume that is your intention.